# Rational Hodge Theory

Tags: hodge-theory, rational-homotopy-theory, formality

I am currently learning about the formality result for Kaehler manifolds proved in DGMS. Their result uses some basic Hodge theory, and so only gives formality over $\mathbf{R}$. Later, however, Sullivan argues that formality for (nilpotent) dgas descends so that formality holds for subfields (using the fact that the algebraic group of automorphisms of a dga is a unipotent extension of the group of automorphisms of its homology). In particular we get formality over $\mathbf{Q}$. This seems somewhat roundabout, as in this paper the real homotopy type of smooth manifolds is obtained by tensoring up the rational version. That is, the minimal model of smooth de Rham forms is shown to agree with tensoring the minimal model of rational PL-forms and then one appeals to the Sullivan/Quillen characterization.

My question is if there is a known way of deducing formality, over $\mathbf{Q}$,of Kaehler manifolds directly? I guess what I'm asking for is a kind of rational Hodge decomposition in this setting.